# Minecraft Protocol Player Movement mcprotocollib

Tags: java, networking, minecraft, packets

i am using Mcprotocollib ( https://github.com/Steveice10/MCProtocolLib ) to make a minecraft character move on the x axis 10 steps but all it does is stand still.

heres what i have https://gist.github.com/CivilizedGravy/32ebb0d616beed1d7ce3

it may be something with the timing of the packet sending. I just need someone to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Change the stance 0.1 to playerY-1.62. Stance is the headY of the player.